# Latex .dtx file with a newcommand called \task

Tags: latex

I have been trying to create a .dtx file for generating a .sty style file. Doing so I found something very strange I don't understand. In my .dtx file I want a macro called \task. If I create the macro with `\newcommand{\task}[2]{Two arguments: #1 and #2}`, then the documentation generation does not work, while if I use the TeX way of declaration ( `\def\task#1#2{Two arguments: #1 and #2}` ) then it works.
Below is the skeleton.dtx file.

```
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\ProvidesFile{skeleton.dtx}
%</driver>
%<package>\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]
%<package>\ProvidesPackage{skeleton}
%<*package>
    [2004/11/05 v1.0 .dtx skeleton file]
%</package>
%
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{skeleton}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{skeleton.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
% \CheckSum{0}
% \DescribeMacro{\task}
% \task{first}{second}
% \StopEventually{}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand{\task}[2]{Two arguments: #1 and #2}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \Finale
\endinput
```

Here is the skeleton.ins file:

```
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\usedir{tex/latex/skeleton}
\generate{\file{skeleton.sty}{\from{skeleton.dtx}{package}}}
\endbatchfile
```

To test, it simply run:

```
latex skeleton.ins
latex skeleton.dtx
```

The first command creates the .sty file, and the second generates the documentation.

With the \newcommand version, the output is

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \task already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.26 ...ommand{\task}[2]{Two arguments: #1 and #2}
```

When using the TeX version of the macro everything works fine. To make it work, just replace the `\newcommand` with `\def\task#1#2{Two arguments: #1 and #2}`

It is to be noted that using another name than "task" does not generate the issue, so it is related to the name of the macro. Dealing with the TeX works fine, but I would like to understand why this \task macro name is an issue.

Many thanks if can explain why.

Finally I found the issue. The class ltxdoc declares a macro `\task` which is empty. I found that this command is used in various base Latex packages (ltoutput, ltpage, ltfloat, ...), and serves as a todo command. In the official ltxdoc.cls package it simply removes what is inside, and I think the maintainers have another implementation to track some todo lists.

This answers my initial question.

Comment: You can add `\show\task` (in front of the \newcommand) to see the definition in the log and make a guess where it's defined. Do you happen to include the tasks package?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Actually I found that \task is defined at the very end of ltxdoc.cls, the class used for generating the documentation. Its definition is `\def\task#1#2{}`, but I don't really get why it is useful.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it has been introduced for some reason, but the ltxdoc documentation doesn't mention anything about it. It's empty, and I think it's unused. It should be safe to overwrite its definition with `\renewcommand` if you want to stick to that name.

Comment: I found that this command is used in various base Latex packages (ltoutput, ltpage, ltfloat, ...), and serves as a todo command. In the official ltxdoc.cls package it simply removes what is inside, and I think the maintainers have another implementation to track some todo lists. I think my best option is to choose another name, as `\renewcommand` would do the deal for generating the doc, but then won't work in another document. Thanks for your help in finding all that.

Answer (score 0):

`\newcommand{\foo}` is a LaTeX command that conditions on whether or not the command to-be-defined - `\foo` - exists or not. If it already exists, an error is generated, otherwise it is created. `\renewcommand{\foo}` checks to see if `\foo` is already defined and subsequently redefines it, otherwise it generates an error.

The above-mentioned LaTeX macros have been made to perform some checks (about the existence of the macro/argument). However, if you revert back to the TeX definition of a macro, `\def` will always overwrite any definition, regardless of its existence. That's just the way this part of the LaTeX macro-layer was designed.

So, if you don't care about redefining any existing creations, you can use `\def` and they'll be overwritten. If you are concerned about overwriting existing things, you can either use `\providecommand{\foo}` (it only creates `\foo` if it doesn't exist) or use a "namespace" to separate your definitions from others (like `\newcommand{\myPackagefoo}` that would be specific to `myPackage`-type macros).

Reference:

- [What do `\newcommand`, `\renewcommand`, and `\providecommand` do, and how do they differ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36175/5764)
- [`source2e.pdf`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) (section **11.3 Command definitions**)